# Do i need to clear Set in javascript to free memory?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, set

After programming with some C i'm a bit worried about memory management...

Let's say i have a Set in JS. It has `Set.prototype.clear` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Set/clear).

Do i need to call .clear for the garbage collector to free memory when i'm done with the Set ?

Comment: Why not consult the resource you're already using? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management

Comment: No, you just need to let go of the Set instance itself to get it garbage-collected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, javascript has its own garbage collection system built in, so clearing it wont be necessary. The clear() method is a convenience method to use when working with sets