# set variable to null is enough to free memory after a test?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

I am reading stuff about test driven development. And I am reading about beforeEach() and afterEach() functions. In the following example variable containe is initialized. Used in beforeEach() and removed in afterEach(). Is this enough to free memory? Is enough set variables to null?

```
import { unmountComponentAtNode } from "react-dom";

let container = null;

beforeEach(() => {
  container = document.createElement("div");
  document.body.appendChild(container);
});

afterEach(() => {
  unmountComponentAtNode(container);
  container.remove();
  container = null;
});
```

I dont know instruments to see memory. Are there tool for this? To see that previusly allocated memory is now free? I know that in javascript, that hav its own garbage collector, [is not necessary to free memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46696208/do-i-need-to-clear-set-in-javascript-to-free-memory). Is this useless doubt?

Comment: Setting the variable to `null` does remove the reference to the div element object, yes. Whether that is enough to free its memory depends on whether there are any other references to it.